# Connect to multiple accounts

Tags: android, account

I am planning to make a locator app in android java language. What I want to know is, how can I connect multiple accounts to the main/admin account so that I can track them? I want to have the options of adding the other accounts through sending digit codes to the email address and phone number.

I want to know what specific classes, libraries or any other ways needed for that.

Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firebase's Firestore then simply add the user's Uid to admins document in a String array considering that you have a structure like `Users (collection) > Uid (document)`.

Similarly, every user should have a unique code that can be sent from admin to the user that has to be added and a mechanism to prevent unknown users from getting added to admins location array.

Comment: Thanks... Do you have a link of a sample code and documentation? I am familiar with firebase realtime database but not firestore.

Comment: @Rho [Firestore's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) is amazing! You can find sample for different languages there.